# Select all adjacent values in multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, xna

I'm building a bubble breaker-kinda game. My code uses two 2D arrays, one containing color indexes (1 - 6) to represent colored circles, and one indicating whether the circle has been selected (1 or 0). I can succesfully select a circle, the right value in the second array changes and this is reflected correctly on screen.

This is the method that selects one circle and four adjacent circles. I pass in the X and Y coordinates that the user has selected on the grid. I set that position to selected (from 0 to 1 in the SelectedCircles array. Check whether any of the sides has a circle with the same color, if so, change that circle to selected too.

```
   private void SelectSurroundingCircles(int xPosition, int yPosition)
    {
        SelectedCircles[yPosition, xPosition] = 1;
        int colorKey = Circles[yPosition, xPosition];

        int increment = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Nickles.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Circles[yPosition - increment, xPosition] == colorKey)
                SelectedCircles[yPosition - increment, xPosition] = 1; // TOP

            if (Circles[yPosition + increment, xPosition] == colorKey)
                SelectedCircles[yPosition + increment, xPosition] = 1; // BOTTOM

            if (Circles[yPosition, xPosition + increment] == colorKey)
                SelectedCircles[yPosition, xPosition + increment] = 1; // RIGHT

            if (Circles[yPosition, xPosition - increment] == colorKey)
                SelectedCircles[yPosition, xPosition - increment] = 1; // LEFT
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is that all circles of the same color that are next to each other get selected. Basically you first look at the circles adjacent as above, look at their adjacent circles, and so on... I tried various other things but somehow I couldn't figure it out. Hopefully someone can help me, I must be overlooking something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this fullfills your exact selecting logic but isn't recursion the solution:

```
if ( SelectedCircles[yPosition - increment, xPosition] != 1 && Circles[yPosition - increment, xPosition] == colorKey) {
   SelectSurroundingCircles(xPosition, yPosition - increment)
}
//... same for other 3 directions
```

The extra check if the position isn't selected already is important to prevent endless recursion

Comment: The problem is that I'm not only checking the top, left, bottom and right circles. I need to check the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right ones too which is giving me headaches. I've tried so many things without luck -_-

Comment: So you need 8 checks in total (NW, N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W) Isn't that just 4 more ifs than your have now and it's done?

Comment: doesn't work for me. Only the first 8 surrounding get checked, then the pattern starts going crazy.

Comment: I patched the code (did you detect it was wrong?) The extra check to prevent endless recursion was wrong creating endless recursion :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it myself. I checked against the array of selected circles, this worked.

```
            for (int y = 0; y < SelectedCircles.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < SelectedCircles.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    if (SelectedCircles[y, x] == 1)
                    {
                        if (y - 1 >= 0 && SelectedCircles[y - 1, x] != 1 && Circles[y - 1, x] == colorKey)
                            SelectedCircles[y - 1, x] = 1; // TOP

                        if (y + 1 <= 9 && SelectedCircles[y + 1, x] != 1 && Circles[y + 1, x] == colorKey)
                            SelectedCircles[y + 1, x] = 1; // BOTTOM

                        if (x + 1 <= 9 && SelectedCircles[y, x + 1] != 1 && Circles[y, x + 1] == colorKey)
                            SelectedCircles[y, x + 1] = 1; // RIGHT

                        if (x - 1 >= 0 && SelectedCircles[y, x - 1] != 1 && Circles[y, x - 1] == colorKey)
                            SelectedCircles[y, x - 1] = 1; // LEFT
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```